# Delete user model

Tags: django

How can I delete the user model? what will be the views?

***urls.py:***

```
path('account_delete/<int:user_delete>', views.account_delete, name="account_delete")
```

***views.py:***

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
def account_delete(request,user_delete):

    return redirect("/")
```

***Templates:***

```
<a href="{ url 'account_delete' user_delete=user_delete }" class="delete_btn btn">
                                        <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                    </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def account_delete(request,user_delete):
    
    # I assume that user_delete is the primary key of the user model
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=user_delete)

    # Delete user
    user.delete()

    return redirect("/")
```

That said I rather recommend the use of forms to do this. See django FormView